# Can I add a Molecular Absorption factor in the Path Loss Model?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am wondering if I could add this molecular absorption factor in the attenuation part of the SimplePathLossModel.cc of the Omnet++ project.

```
 // the part of the attenuation only depending on the distance
double distFactor = pow(sqrDistance, -pathLossAlphaHalf) / (16.0 * M_PI * M_PI);
EV_TRACE << "distance factor is: " << distFactor << endl;

Signal attenuation(signal->getSpectrum());
for (uint16_t i = 0; i < signal->getNumValues(); i++) {
    double wavelength = BaseWorldUtility::speedOfLight() / signal->getSpectrum().freqAt(i);
    attenuation.at(i) = (wavelength * wavelength) * distFactor;
}
*signal *= attenuation;
```

This molecular absorption factor will be added in order to get the best results out of a Terahertz Frequency simulation and also this factor will indeed depend on the distance.

What would you guys recommend me ? 
Where should I add it?

Comment: If the general assumptions of SimplePathLoss still hold in your model, I’d recommend creating an additional analogueModel which could then be used as one more component of path loss. That is, a node in your simulation would apply two analogueModels to every transmission received: SimplePathLoss and your new one.